# Display Custom Fields Meta Box on Category, Tags and CPT

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to Add Custom Field on All Tags, Category and Custom Post Type (Taxonomy) but with below code get custom field option only on All Category.
How to get on All **Tags,** Categories and **CPT Taxonomy** as well?

```
function wecode_category_fields($taxonomies) {
         if (current_filter() == 'category_edit_form_fields') {  
            $Pincode = get_term_meta( $taxonomies->term_id, 'Pincode', true );  
            ?>
         
       <tr class="form-field">
        <th valign="top" scope="row"><label for="Pincode"><?php _e('Pincode'); ?></label></th>
           <td>
              <input type="text" size="40" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $Pincode ) ? esc_attr( $Pincode ) : ''; ?>"  name="Pincode"><br/>
                  <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter your Pincode'); ?></span>
           </td> 
       </tr>  
    
    
        <?php } elseif (current_filter() == 'category_add_form_fields') {
            ?> 
            <div class="form-field">
                <label for="Pincode"><?php _e('Pincode'); ?></label>
                <input type="text" size="40" value=""  name="Pincode">
                <p class="description"><?php _e('Please enter your Pincode'); ?></p>
            </div> 
      
        <?php
        } }
    
    add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'wecode_category_fields', 10, 2);
    add_action('category_add_form_fields', 'wecode_category_fields', 10, 2); 
    
    function wecode_save_category_fields($term_id) {
        if ( isset( $_REQUEST['Pincode'] ) ) { 
            $Pincode = $_REQUEST['Pincode']; 
                 
               update_term_meta( $term_id, 'Pincode', $Pincode );   
        }  }
    add_action('edited_category', 'wecode_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
    add_action('create_category', 'wecode_save_category_fields', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

if You want to get all tag/category of custom post types then use the below code.

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'testimonial_tag', // here you can add you custom taxonomy name
    'hide_empty' => false,
]); 
$result =  new WP_Query($terms);
```

If you want to get a particular custom field value from a particular taxonomy/tag then use below code

```
    echo get_field('tes', 'testimonial_tag_18');
eg : get_field('custom-field-name', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);
```

Comment: No, i'm trying to insert new CF and CF Value separately to Custom Taxonomy. Taxonomy is created through [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-types/) plugin. Screenshot - https://ibb.co/WVy8vRk | 
https://ibb.co/gVpmY2N

Comment: Okay, Do you want to get pin code custom field value of all post category or single category?

Comment: I want to insert separate Custom Field Values in Single Category. I just need to show Pincode CF Form on the Taxonomy edit window. As you have seen Screenshot The CF Form (Pincode) is available for Category but not for Taxonomy.